# Why is $('div :not(script)').contents().filter(function() causing escaped HTML characters to become unescaped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Building a Chrome Extension for a click to call API and I've run into a problem where I've noticed some pages are displaying strange... I've narrowed it down to this piece of code.

```
var rxpCtc = new RegExp("([0-9_]+\.?[0-9 ]{6,})(?!([^<]+)?>)(?!(<script>+)?>)", "gm");
$('div :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
return this.nodeValue.replace(rxpCtc, "<span class='gr-wrap'>$1</span>");
});
$('.gr-wrap').css('color', 'green' );
```

It seems to cause escaped HTML characters like `&lt;` to become `<`

Why does this happen? Any suggestions for a fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) of a text node gives you the *plain text* rendered in that node; the `nodeValue` doesn't give you (possibly escaped) HTML, but *text*.

```js
const d = document.createElement('div')
d.innerHTML = '&lt;'
console.log(d.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

I don't see any properties on the text node interface that give you the text string as escaped HTML, but you could append the text node to a new element and take that new element's `innerHTML`:

```js
const d = document.createElement('div')
d.innerHTML = '&lt;'

// Extract the unescaped text
const text = d.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.textContent = text;
console.log(newDiv.innerHTML);
```

For your code, instead of doing

```
return this.nodeValue.replace(rxpCtc, "<span class='gr-wrap'>$1</span>");
```

do

```
return escape(this.nodeValue).replace(rxpCtc, "<span class='gr-wrap'>$1</span>");
```

```
const escape = text => {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.textContent = text;
  return newDiv.innerHTML;
};
```